# JSON Encoding of an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to fetch results from the database into an array and then encoding that array into a json string but it does not echo any results. Can anybody figure out why?

```
$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $unique_array[] = array('id'=>$row['id'], 'name'=>$row['name'],'province'=>$row['province']);
}

echo(json_encode($unique_array));
```

Comment: Are you sure your getting data from database?

Comment: Add `var_dump($unique_array);` right before the `echo(json_` , just in order to make sure that the `while` loop is running and populating that variable.

Comment: also stop using deprecated Mysql functionalities and switch to Mysqli or better PDO

Comment: json_encode returns true or false nothing will echo

Comment: @SunilPachlangia Wut?

Comment: For the purpose of debugging, I'd rather use `var_dump` instead of `echo`, so you also see values like `FALSE`.

Comment: Use this $array = json_encode($unique_array); then var_dump($array);

Answer (score 2):

If the encoding fails, the function will return FALSE, and nothing will be echoed.

You can check errors with: `json_last_error()` and find the meaning here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

or for humans with this: `json_last_error_msg();`

```
$encoded_array = json_encode($unique_array);
if( json_last_error() ) {
    echo(json_last_error_msg());
    var_dump($unique_array);
}
else {
    echo($encoded_array);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot!
the error was "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded". Adding this line after setting the connection with database solved it:
mysql_set_charset("utf8");

Comment: Glad to here it. It's usually not what you think is the problem at actually is the problem.